# React-native transform view to fullscreen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm trying to do [this animation](https://material.google.com/motion/material-motion.html#material-motion-what-makes-a-good-transition) (the pesto bruschetta)

I have a listView with a couple of cards with a specific width/height. and I need to make one fullScreen with additionnal information when I click on it (so with the onPress).

I'm using : `react-native: 0.30.0` and `react-native-router-flux: 3.33.0` for the routing between Scene/Activity

Anyone whould have an idea of how to do the fullscreen transformation?

Specifically to `react-native-router-flux` or not. I have tried using `LayoutAnimation` from `react-native`, but nothing was working (and the only exmaple i found online wasn't compiling)

Comment: Did you find any way to do that? I'm stuck with that too

Answer (score 0):

read code for react-native-lightbox.